# Is it possible to modify Outlook's AutoFormat from VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

basically, I want to be able to edit the AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks property so that I can click on links in the Reading Pane.  I know I can do this manually, but I need a repeatable programmatic solution I can deploy to multiple users.

I know it can be done in Word, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Outlook.

Comment: Do you mean the "Show images and hyperlinks" popup menu in the preview pane?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to programmatically toggle the checkbox "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks" found at the following location:

Outlook > File > Options > Mail (menu) > Editor Options... (button) > AutoCorrect Options... (button) > AutoFormat (tab)

It is the last checkbox under the Replace section.

Comment: It is probably in one of the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook registry keys...

Comment: According to MS, the option can be modified in the Registry as you suggested
(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982113).  But I do not want to make such a
broad change.  Instead, I'm trying to only display the clickable URL only if
certain keywords are found in the body of the received email.

Btw, I see that it's possible in Word
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212615(v=office.11).aspx), but I
can't find a similar property in Outlook.

Comment: I just noticed a weird "thing" with that registry key.  When I manually toggle the checkbox in the AutoFormat settings, it does not change the registry key.  That suggests that the setting is store elsewhere, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do this through the Word object model, you should be able to access the Word's Document object of the message displayed in the preview pane using Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).GetInspector.WordEditor